# Xcode 7 Expected Expression Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have problem in iOS application development using sqlite.

When coding following code, there is an error on line `sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;` it says

> "Expected Expression".

Please Help me find solution.

```
-(void)runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable {

    // Create a sqlite object.
    sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;

    //Set the database file path.
    NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];

    // Initialize the results array.
    if (self.arrResults != nil){
        [self.arrResults removeAllObjects];
        self.arrResults = nil;
    }

    self.arrResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Initialize the column names array.
    if (self.arrColumnNames != nil){
        [self.arrColumnNames removeAllObjects];
        self.arrColumnNames = nil;
    }

    self.arrColumnNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database.
    BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database);

    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK)
        // Declare a sqlite3_stmt object in which will be stored the query after having been compiled into a SQLite statement.
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        // Load all data from database to memory.
        BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, query, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

        if (prepareStatementResult == SQLITE_OK){
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that you've forgotten a bracket at the end of the if statement before that line. The definition isn't enough to be on its own in an if statement and you want to protect more than just the definition anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Wain.

Comment: Why do I have to insert  a bracket at the end of the if statement before that line? I'm a beginner. Please tell me in detail.

Comment: because you have multiple statements protected by that if, and a simple empty declaration isn't really a statement

Comment: @Wain You do want the pointer. It needs to be `sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, i wasn't sure. removed that part and expanded the rest